# jQuery counting elements with attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery code wich is counting some divs where certain Breakfast board are found as below

```
var board_bb1 = $('div[data-board="Bed And Breakfast"]').length;
        var board_bb2 = $('div[data-board="Breakfast"]').length;
        var board_bb3 = $('div[data-board="Breakfast Buffet"]').length;
        var board_bb4 = $('div[data-board="Breakfast (Full Breakfast)"]').length;   
        var board_bb5 = $('div[data-board="Continental Breakfast"]').length;
        var board_bb8 = $('div[data-board="Bed and Breakfast"]').length;
        var board_bb6 = $('div[data-board="Full Breakfast"]').length;
        var board_bb7 = $('div[data-board="Breakfast (Continental Breakfast)"]').length;
        var board_bb = board_bb1 + board_bb2  + board_bb3 + board_bb4 + board_bb5 + board_bb6 + board_bb7 + board_bb8;
```

The attributes from data-board are coming from an API service, and sometimes is breakfast sometimes is Breakfast, bed And Breakfast etc.
        Is there a way to simply the above code to count all the divs who has the word Breakfast in  data-board

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("div[data-board*='Breakfast']").length
```

The `*=` part will look for any attribute containing the word `breakfast.`

**IF** you are not using jQuery in your project, in modern browsers this will work to:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div[data-board*='Breakfast']").length;
```

To complete it: a cross-browser solution that will work all the way back to IE5.5

```
var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0, i < allDivs.length; i++)
{
   if (allDivs[i].getAttribute("data-board") && allDivs[i].getAttribute("data-board").match(/Breakfast/) )
   {
      count++;
   }
}
```

After this `count` will return the amount of divs containing the word `Breakfast` in the `data-board` attribute

Comment: `^=` is 'Starts with'. You probably meant `*=` that is 'Contains'.

Comment: its counting only the elements who has this attribute: "Breakfast" not all of them

Comment: Sorry @haim770 is right. It's early in the morning, mixed them up :-). Updated it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `~` operator

```
$("div[data-board~='Breakfast']").length
```